psycopg2 : can't run on 'localhost' (127.0.0.1) and cannot accept TCP/IP connection
Disclaimer: I did a lot of research throughout the internet for the solutions, but somehow none of them solve my case
Background: I want to directly connect my ML python source code to my DBMS which is Postgre using psycopg2.
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname = '<databasename>', 
    user = 'postgres', 
    password = '<mypass>', 
    host = 'localhost',
    port = '5432',
    requiressl = 0
    )

cursor = connection.cursor()

Error: Somehow it throws me an error like this
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

It seems like the port is listening only to the localhost IP (127.0.0.1).
What I've done:

Stated from other sources, it seems like we have to adjust the listening addresses through the postgresql.conf file so that the machine could give permission for access outside the local one.
I also did change the pg_hba.conf source code, by changing

IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32         scram-sha-256
to
IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256
I restarted the machine, but still nothings work.
I also did make sure that my port is listening to the right address
Listens list
Note: My directories for the 2 files above is \Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data<both files> and I am running on Windows


It is Postgresql or Postgres not Postgre. 2) DO NOT use images for textual data. 3) If your client is external(this includes VMs and containers) to the Postgres server connecting to localhost is not going to work. You need to connect to whatever the hostname/ip address is for the server machine. Also make sure the firewall(if up and running) allows access to port 5432.


"It seems like the port is listening only to the localhost IP (127.0.0.1)"  How did you conclude that?  The error message suggests it is not listening to that.


well the thing is my server is running on localhost (127.0.0.1), either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' solves it  2) I did create a new rule for the firewall to allow access to port 5432 but nothings work. @AdrianKlaver


Yeah, and I assumed that's why it failed. It only listens to localhost, that is why external machine cant connect to my database. I'm assuming it failed because I am using external machine. I'm not sure man, I am actually a bit confused too @jjanes

I don't understand what your question is.  The code you show failing does use 'localhost', but then you say that using 'localhost' solves it. So what is failing?

The image shows it is listening on 0.0.0.0, which I'm guessing means you have listen_addresses set to either * or 0.0.0.0 in postgresql.conf.  The issue is not the address the server is listening on, it is the address you are having the client connect to. 127.0.0.1/localhost is only going to work if the client is on the same 'machine' as the server. If you want to connect from outside 'machine'  you need to point the client at the IP address or hostname that the 'machine' exposes to external clients. That is not 127.0.0.1/localhost.
